# Is ChromeDriver crashing?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Does this error mean ChromeDriver is crashing?

System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException : no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
(Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.200)

Is there a way to prevent this?